# Approaching boss against going full-time in the summer at my student job

Tags: student, part-time

**Background**

I am a part-time junior software developer for a small company for a little more than 2 years now. I'm still a student, which means, during my semester, I work 20-30 hours a week, but for the past years, both of the summers I were on full-time (40hr/week). I started college in Computer Science 1 year into the job, I was full-time before that.

When I was recruited as a junior with zero-to-little programming experience (only ~1 year self taught, no college), my salary increases were tied to performance "checkmarks" and official, international exams (set by my supervisors). I always had 2-3 months to complete each step, and I usually did it in 1-2 months (always about 3-6 weeks early).
Of course, my salary increases were also tied to this.

**My intention**

As a result, since I don't want to leave this job (yet), I thought I would do Google Summer of Code this year, as I am still a college student, and I would benefit from it greatly. This would not be possible if I went full-time.

**How do I tell my boss I don't want to switch back to full-time for the summer?**

Answer (score 6):

> How do I tell my boss I don't want to switch back to full-time for the
>   summer?

Just tell your boss what you want and why.

Something like "Boss. I'm planning to do Google Summer of Code this year. So I won't be able to work full time this summer. I would like to continue to work part-time though." should work.

Then, listen to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to realize that you are the master of your time, so as long as you do not have agreed to a contract that says otherwise, you do not have to go full time anyways.

So depending on that, you may not even *have* to approach them at all. Of course it would be a nice gesture to let them know in advance - and as your goal is to further you education so you´ll be even more valuable in the future they should actually support this.

So if you do not have a contract, binding you to work full time in the summer, just tell them like you told us. If you want to be extra-sure there is no confusion, you could also write a mail-reminder to management, preferably after telling them in person so you leave a paper trail.